# Enterprise Edition doesn't showing Manage Existing Extensions in Magento Connect?

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have Magento Enterprise Edition. In my magento Connect manager panel doesn't showing Manage existing extensions, even though I hit the **Check for Update**  button. But doesn't showing existing extensions.

But I have magento community edition also in this showing Manage existing extensions. If I hit the **Check for Update**  button.showing existing extensions and new version information.

But Magento Enterprise Edistion doesn't showing why?

can any one tell me how to upgrade 1.12 to 1.13?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are official instructions about this. Take a look:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-upgrading

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee11302-ce18-install-upgrade#upgrade-manual-run